# not getting this header to work correctly

Tags: php

I am still working on this and I been trying to add in different things but its not working. When i go to the web site the side is all messed up and I don't know why.Here is my code:

```
   <?php
// Get all the categories and
// link them to category.php.

// Define and execute the query:
$q = 'SELECT category_id, category FROM categories ORDER BY category';
$r = mysqli_query($dbc, $q);

// Fetch the results:
while (list($fcid, $fcat) = mysqli_fetch_array($r, MYSQLI_NUM)) {

    // Print as a list item.
    echo "<li><a href=\"category.php?cid=$fcid\">$fcat</a></li>\n";

    if($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']!="CART FILE"){
                echo "<h1>Cart Contents</h1>";
                echo "<div class=\"p2\">";
                $itemCount = count($_SESSION['cart']);
                foreach($_SESSION['cart'] as X=>X){

                    for($i=0;$i<count(X);$i++){
                        $itemCount+=X;
                      }

                }
                echo "<a href=\"cart.php\">You have ".$itemCount." total items in your cart.</a>";
                echo "</div>\n";
        }

} // End of while loop.
```

When I change the x=>x to $k=>$v nothing happens. I don't understand this at all the count comes up but the sides is all out of whack. Here is the website http://www.elinkswap.com/snorris/header.html I am sure it is something small but I am still a newbie at this.

ok I am editing this maybe for you guys to understand what i am trying to do here it is:
add in how many items are in the cart on the right side that is what this code is suppose to do..

Comment: please change title of your question...

Comment: Why would I change the title I am not understanding this

Comment: dude, try renaming to header.php

Comment: ok i edit and also edit to see if you guys can understand what i am asking.

Comment: @st1984, this site is about questions on particular problems, but "please why I can't get this work" doesn't tell anything, it's not a specific problem.

Comment: @st1984 no, your code doesn't do anything, it just gets rendedered as html on the page. It's messed up because the browser gets confused by the tags. And now gives error 500

Comment: I am loading everything back up to the site its almost uploaded again damien

Comment: http://www.elinkswap.com/snorris/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change this:

```
foreach($_SESSION['cart'] as X=>X){
   for($i=0;$i<count(X);$i++){
      $itemCount+=X;
  }
}
```

to this:

```
foreach($_SESSION['cart'] as $key=>$X)
{
   for($i=0;$i<count($X);$i++){
      $itemCount+= $X;
   }
}
```

It should work.

Comment: Or just `as $X`, don't see the key being used here. EDIT: The for-loop only counts the length of the array? Why not just use `count($X)` instead?

Comment: @OptimusCrime Indeed it seams to sum same values instead of count them.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that your page is interpreted as a php script ? Default extension of the page to be taken into account by the interpreter is .php, maybe .php3 .php5 depending on the version.

Or maybe you're using some url rewriting I don't see.